# Excel conditional formatting - adding search function to ISNUMBER

Tags: excel-formula, conditional-statements, conditional-formatting

I am trying to solve conditional formatting problem.

I have formula which highlight start date and end date:

```
=ISNUMBER(VLOOKUP(D5;accomodation_2024!$G:$G;1;0)) - start date
=ISNUMBER(VLOOKUP(D5;accomodation_2024!$H:$H;1;0)) - end date
```

What I am trying to add is one condition which firstly check whether in another sheet in the column F is text "studio" only then highlight start date and end date. At the moment in that column F are two texts "studio" & "apartment"

This is what I am using but it did not work.

```
=IF(OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Studio";accomodation_2024!$F$7:$F$14)));ISNUMBER(VLOOKUP(D5;accomodation_2024!$G$7:$G$101;1;0)))
=IF(OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Studio";accomodation_2024!$F$7:$F$14)));ISNUMBER(VLOOKUP(D5;accomodation_2024!$H$7:$H$101;1;0)))
=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Studio";accomodation_2024!$F$7:$F$14)));ISNUMBER(VLOOKUP(D5;accomodation_2024!$G$7:$G$101;1;0)))
=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Studio";accomodation_2024!$F$7:$F$14)));ISNUMBER(VLOOKUP(D5;accomodation_2024!$H$7:$H$101;1;0)))
```

OR:

```
=IF(OR(ISNUMBER(VLOOKUP(D5;accomodation_2024!$G$7:$G$101;1;0)));ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Studio";accomodation_2024!$F$7:$F$14)))
=IF(OR(ISNUMBER(VLOOKUP(D5;accomodation_2024!$H$7:$H$101;1;0)));ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Studio";accomodation_2024!$F$7:$F$14)))
```

OR:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(accomodation_2024!$F$7:$F$101="Studio")*(ISNUMBER(VLOOKUP(D5;accomodation_2024!$G$7:$G$101;1;0))))>0
```

But it always highlight both dates for "studio" & "apartment", but I need only for "studio".

Comment: Try `=ISNUMBER(MATCH(1,(accomodation_2024!$F$7:$F$101="Studio")*(accomodation_2024!$G$7:$G$101=D5),0))`.

Comment: May I ask another question, is it possible to extend this formula to find same date (or overlapping date) in two columns? For example, I have start date in column $G$7:$G$101, and end date in column $H$7:$H$101. Sometime the start date is the same as end date. The same precondition should applied if "accomodation_2024!$F$7:$F$101="Studio") than highlight cell where the start date is the same as end date. Thanks.